# How to call a function in another C file with a subset of the command-line arguments?

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

How can I call this `convert` function using command line and from argument 2 onwards start converting the strings to int and store in an array?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc , char* argv[])
{
    int i;
 
    if (argc < 2)

    {
        printf("Error: Less than two arguments\n");
    }
    else 
    {
        for(i=0; i<argc; i++)
        {
            printf("[%d] : %s\n", i , argv[i]); 
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Function in the same directory but in a separate C file:

```
void convert ( char* parray[] ,int array[] )
{   
    int i;
 
    printf("The converted array = ");

    for (i=0; i< LENGTH; i++)
    {
        array[i] = atoi(parray[i]);

        printf(" %d" , array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: OT: the function `atoi()` does not inform the program when an error occurs.  Suggest using `strtol()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a module, have the declarations in a separate file, and the implementations in a separate.

**functions.h:**

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H /* include guard */
#define FUNCTIONS_H

void convert(char *parray[], int array[], int length);

#endif
```

**functions.c:**

```
#include "functions.h" /* include your header with the declarations */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void convert(char *parray[], int array[], int length)
{

    int i;

    printf("The converted array = ");

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = atoi(parray[i]);

        printf(" %d", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return;
}
```

**main.c:**

```
#include "functions.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, *arr = NULL;

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Error: Less than two arguments\n");
    }
    else
    {
        arr = malloc((argc - 1) * sizeof(int)); /* array can be static too */

        if (arr == NULL)
        {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            /* handle error */
        }

        convert(&argv[1], arr, argc - 1);

        free(arr); /* free when you exit */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Compilation:**

`clang -c functions.c && clang main.c functions.o`

OR

`clang functions.c main.c`

**Output:**

```
$ ./a.out 15 20 -90 18 20 20 8 8 8 81
$ The converted array =  15 20 -90 18 20 20 8 8 8 81
```

Comment: What if we want a static array and start the conversion from argument 2 on wards not from argument 1 !! Mr. Alex?

Comment: Well in that case, you will need to edit the function call. `convert(&argv[2], arr, argc - 2);`, `arr` doesn't need to change. Even if you choose to be static.

Comment: @Anas Then just modify, `*arr` -> `arr[SIZE]` and remove the `malloc()` and `free()` calls. With `SIZE` being the desired size.

Answer (score 1):

You can compile both files into the same executable, e.g like:

```
gcc -o main main.c convert.c
```

To use the function in `convert.c` in `main.c`, you will have to declare the function before you define the `main()` function, like this:

```c
#include<stdio.h>

void convert ( char* parray[] ,int array[] );

int main (int argc , char* argv[])
{
    // your code ..

    //you may now use the convert function inside the main function
    convert(param1, param2);
}
```

Alternatively, you could create a header file for `convert.c`, called `convert.h`, like this:

```c
#ifndef CONVERT_H
#define CONVERT_H

void convert ( char* parray[] ,int array[] );

#endif
```

Then, you could include the headerfile in the main file like this:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include "convert.h"

int main (int argc , char* argv[])
{
    // use convert here somewhere
    convert(param1, param2);
}
```